# Trigger event on pusher (React native)

Tags: react-native, pusher-js

I'm trying to trigger an event with pusher but returns Error.
I can listen but when I try to trigger doesn't work, this how I'm trying:

```
const channel = pusherClient.subscribe('channel');

channel.trigger('event', {
   name: 'John',
   age: 20
});
```

Comment: What package are you using to bring in subscribe to react-native?

Comment: I'm using pusher-js

Comment: Can you post all code for the above Component?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled client-side triggering? Is a setting you found on Pusher admin page.

Comment: Yes, its enabled.